# pd.to_datetime wrong format

Tags: python, string-to-datetime

I have a dataframe `df`, where I want to set the column 'Time' to a datetimeindex. The column before converting looks like this:

```
01-10-19    09:05
01-10-19    10:04
01-10-19    11:05
01-10-19    12:04
01-10-19    13:04
            ...  
31-05-20    22:05
31-05-20    23:05
01-06-20    00:05
01-06-20    01:05
01-06-20    02:05
```

So I tried the following line of code:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%d-%m-%Y    %H:%M', errors='coerce')
```

Which lead to only NaT 'values' in the column, without datetimeindex being installed. I've also tried to change the format in multiple ways such as: `'%%dd-%%mm-%%YY    %%HH:%%MM'` or `'%d%d-%m%m-%Y%Y    %H%H:%M%M'`, but it resulted in the same error.
When I remove the `errors='coerce'`, I got the message: `ValueError: time data '09:05' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y    %H:%M' (match)`. What am I missing? Why is it the wrong format and how do I fix it? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that is all one column? The error you are getting suggests that the date and time are in separate columns.

Comment: You're right, apparently the dataframe already has an index which is indeed the date column. Rookie mistake... But fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], infer_datetime_format= True)
print(df)

#output:
                 Time
0 2019-01-10 09:05:00
1 2019-01-10 10:04:00
2 2019-01-10 11:05:00
3 2019-01-10 12:04:00
4 2019-01-10 13:04:00
5 2020-05-31 22:05:00
6 2020-05-31 23:05:00
7 2020-01-06 00:05:00
8 2020-01-06 01:05:00
9 2020-01-06 02:05:00
```